# Having a custom fmap traversing until non Functor type is found

Tags: haskell

In my learning curve of Haskell, I am wondering if it possible to implement a custom fmap function, fmap' , that would "apply" until a non Functor is found.

For example; with fmap , one has to write

```
fmap (fmap (*2)) [[1,2] , [ 3,4 ,5]]
[[2,4],[6,8,10]]
```

or

```
fmap (fmap (*2)) [Just 1, Just 2]
[Just 2,Just 4]
```

The idea is to write

```
fmap' (*2) [[1,2] , [3,4,5]]
fmap' (*2) [Just 1 , Just 2]
```

to get the same result as above.

My current understanding is that it is not possible because fmap' and fmap do not have the same signature as

```
:t fmap (fmap) 
fmap (fmap)
  :: (Functor f2, Functor f1) => f1 (a -> b) -> f1 (f2 a -> f2 b)
```

Comment: you should compare it with the type of `fmap . fmap` (*not* `fmap fmap`).  (see also the type for `fmap . fmap . fmap` etc.). -- But I understand that you want `fmap'` to decide how many `fmap`s are in the `.`-connected chain, is this correct?

Comment: You would like to have a function which decides if an arbitrary type has a `Functor` instance, but this isn't possible - it's simply not how type classes work. Typically when people want to do things like this, it's because they hope to save some typing here and there; some context as to what you want to achieve would help.

Comment: @Wil Ness, yes you understood what I aimed to ask

Comment: @user2407038 : no context really, just to help me progressing and understanding haskell tricks;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a function:

```
rfmap :: (a -> b) -> F a -> F b
```

where `F` is some arbitrary "context" of `a`, which may be quite sophisticated.  E.g. one specialization would be:

```
rfmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe (Int -> Either Bool a) -> Maybe (Int -> Either Bool b)
```

We need the typechecker to figure out that `F = Maybe (Int -> Either Bool _)`.  This is not as easy as `fmap`, whose argument is a type constructor applied to a variable

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Compose Maybe (Either Bool) a -> Compose Maybe (Either Bool) b
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and is easily found, because type constructors are injective.

`rfmap` needs to deal with some tricky ambiguities. Consider:

```
rfmap id (Just [42])
```

Which specialization should we choose?

```
rfmap :: (Int -> Int) -> Maybe [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
rfmap :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Maybe [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
rfmap :: (Maybe [Int] -> Maybe [Int]) -> Maybe [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
```

That is, do we consider the functor `Maybe _` or `Maybe (Int -> _)`, or even the identity functor `_`?  You probably want to say "as deep as possible", but alas, that interferes with polymorphism:

```
f :: a -> Maybe a
f x = rfmap id (Just x)
```

You probably want this to just be one `fmap`, because going deeper doesn't typecheck. However if we pass `f [42]` then it's the same as the expression above which goes down two by the "as deep as possible" rule -- so this is something like like a violation of referential transparency (I wouldn't consider it a full violation because there is hidden type-directed information that might differ).

Nevermind that there might be a `Num` instance for a functor, e.g. `Num a => Num (Vector a)`, which would mean that `[42]` is actually *more* than two levels deep.

So there are a lot of hard questions that make something like `rfmap` unlikely to have a well-behaved implementation.

As usual, *if* you give up polymorphism (which is a terrible idea), [you can hack something together with typeclasses](https://github.com/luqui/experiments/blob/master/rfmap.hs).  It also has some other problems.

I would recommend against expecting any solution to be usable.  It's the kind of thing that's not very compatible with Haskell's type system.

As far as alternatives:

- If you are writing a single instance and just annoyed with all the `fmap`s, look at [semantic editor combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators) for a nice way to think about it.
- If you are making abstractions (in the sense of a type w/ operations) which are just nested functors and annoyed by the tedious reimplementation of `fmap = fmap.fmap.fmap`, then using [`Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) is the way to go.

Comment: could you please show how can I map `(*2)` on the numbers inside `[[[1,2]], [[3],[4,5]]]` with `Compose`? I know I can do this with `(fmap.fmap.fmap)` simply.

Comment: @WillNess, that's not really what `Compose` is good at if you're just doing it once, but ok.  `getCompose . getCompose . fmap (*2) . Compose . Compose`

Comment: thanks. I was sure I tried something similar and it didn't work. :) thanks a lot!